# Wasn't Feynman's parton model the same as the quark model?

Tags: nuclear-physics, feynman

In the early sixties of the previous century, the quark model of hadrons was conceived. In 1969 Richard Feynman introduced the parton model of the proton.

Wasn't his parton model simply the same as the quark model? Didn't he "just" put some flesh on the skeletal conception of quarks being present in hadrons?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Wasn't his parton model simply the same as the quark model? Didn't he [Feynman] "just" put some flesh on the skeletal concept of quarks present inside hadrons?

Not at all! Before the discovery of asymptotic freedom (1973; and hence envisioning of confinement), the absence of free quarks and the understanding of how they behaved was all speculation: a bag of intuitive mathematical tricks to produce relations experimentalists could use, without quite believing in quarks. You may think of Gell-Mann, Zweig, and Feynman all landing on completely different parts of a continent, and only barely appreciating they were on the same one. (Of course, all three knew each other: MGM and RPF were competitive/collaborative colleagues sparring with each other every day, and GZ was RPF's PhD student, and ultimately colleague.) But they did not quite align in their vision of the big picture, and all three were subtly off the ultimate one.

1964; Four advances not fully fitting with each other:

- MGM appreciates the "missing" **3** irreducible representation of the flavor SU(3) he had invented three years before would tensor with itself and its conjugate to constitute the extant irreps of hadrons, **8**, **10**, etc, provided their fractional electric charges be 2/3, -1/3, so far unobservable. He boldly, and correctly, wagers that such charges will not be observed in the lab or cosmic rays *directly*, ("physical non-existence of quarks"). He thus ushers in an understanding of his "eightfold-way" flavor-SU(3) hadron classification scheme. Today, these quarks would be understood as constituent ones. (In ignorance of color, difficulties with their statistics and confinement are left in abeyance.)
- [GZ introduces](https://arxiv.org/abs/1007.0494) 3 (4!) quarks, which he calls "aces". These, beyond reproducing SU(3) mass formulas and coupling relations much more simply and perspicuously, explain a dynamical mystery: why the φ vector meson is far more stable than its peers, by dint of his (Zweig's) rule:  quark-antiquark pairs in a hadron are reluctant to annihilate themselves. (Ultimately 2, 3, 4, ..., other names attach themselves to the "rule".) He is less savvy in anticipating criticism, and not yet established, so he is attacked harshly by established physicists, muttering about "charlatan" stuff...
- Gürsey & Radicatti combine SU(3) with spin SU(2) in an SU(6) which is even more spectacularly successful in classifying baryons than flavor SU(3).
- MGM introduces current algebra, a sub-rosa field theory, whose current commutators greatly expedite and clarify electromagnetic & weak amplitudes. Today, we'd recognize the quarks in the currents' bilinears as "current quarks", the constituent quark cores (constituent quarks with no covering) of  valence quarks.

For five years, confusion reigns supreme (Mellosh transform, etc..), despite increasing rewards, fits, and easy computability if one took the quark model seriously. The conservatives would just call them "mathematical" to fob off insistent observability questions; while MGM would describe the QFT currents he studied as a mere crutch to get answers. His analog was a haute-cuisine dish involving cooking a piece of pheasant meat   between two slices of veal, which are then discarded.  (The veal is the QFT machinery!)

1969

- Apprised of Bjorken's conformal arguments to explain scaling in deep inelastic scattering of hadrons by photons, RPF envisions hadrons as swarms of bees (partons) where a projectile (photon given off by an electron) hits just *one* bee and leaves a characteristic relativistic kinematic distribution signature. He explains scaling and its central significance in simple, intuitive terms, and effectively impresses the experimental community to focus on questions that matter. *This marks the beginning of a productive experimental program investigating quarks*. (Abortive searches for free quarks merely confirm their confinement.)

At this point, everyone thinks of parton as quarks, but doesn't say so, so as to avoid unanswerable questions (at that stage, once an identification with quarks were made). Eventually, with careful measurements and additional theoretical work (parton sum rules) it is appreciated that, indeed, the charged partons are zillions of soft quarks, but half the momentum of the baryon is carried by chargeless partons (now identified as gluons: RPF's presciently noncommittal name made sense.)

[A small aside, personally witnessed. MGM was so frustrated by RPF's refusal to call his partons "quarks", that he often referred to them as "put-ons", since "of course they are quarks!!".  With intensity.]

But at that point, everyone, including experimentalists, is sold on quarks, and it is evident they are behind motivating and explaining a spate of DIS experiments. They just know there are mysteries about them, and theorists  shift to overdrive to resolve them.

- It all finally "clicks"  in 1973. First, Gross & Wilczek, and, independently, Politzer, discover asymptotic freedom of nonabelian gauge theories, (weakening of the coupling with increasing energy), thereby explaining DIS scaling in a QFT setting. So QFT is veal no more. Then (even though the work was started in 1972) Bardeen, Gell-Mann and Fritzsch argue for the color degree of freedom, homing in on QCD, the strong interactions' QFT.

Along the way, an awful lot of mistakes were made, misconceptions came and went, and lots of incremental advances and clarifications firmed up the correct, effective, super-accurate QFT theory underlying half of the Standard Model. A highly collective enterprise.

Comment: I was silently hoping you answered this. What can I say?......."Im certainly will sleep good tonight!" is all I can think of... Did you actually see MGM?

Comment: Yes, I was a PhD student there in the late 70s and interacted a lot with all three principal heroes involved. I have met and talked with all persons named above, except Radicatti.

Comment: I cant stop myself from saying: I have found a new ἥρως. Giving almost poetic answers on this and other sites...